# I accidently pressed some shortcut all my tabs and everything disappeared

Tags: interface

Please help me out I am stuck with this now, I am unable to bring back my tabs on top and all those things.
[image]

Comment: maybe try Ctrl Spacebar?

Comment: Hello ! you pressed CTRL + SPACE which maximizes the area where you cursor is hovering. Pretty handy in some situations but you have to know the shortcut to get back ><

Comment: CTRL+ Spacebar doesnt do anything @moonboots

Comment: nvm figured it out its right Alt + spacebar ... idk why but it works thanks everyone

Comment: mmh ok, weird because Ctrl Alt Spacebar exists (maximize area, similar to Ctrl Spacebar and similar to your problem), but I don't know what this Alt Spacebar is

Comment: I don't know why Alt Spacebar doesn't show up in the keymap, but it's not doing the same thing as CTRL Spacebar.  When you _Maximize Area_, it leaves a "back to previous" indicator in the menu bar and leaves the sidebar and toolbar open if they're open.  Alt Spacebar outdoes maximize and removes even the sidebars and top menu, at least in 2.93.5